# Node/Express Node/Request Streaming JSON objects

Tags: json, node.js, express, stream, node-request

I am implementing a node app that uses Node/Request to GET JSON objects then pipe the response to process the incoming objects and pass them further. In the functional test I use Node/Express to mock the actual endpoint that makes a JSON array available. My problem is that the entire array of objects is transferred rather than object by object.

here is the consumer app (simplified):

```
request('http://localhost:3000/processable')
.pipe new ResultStream

class ResultStream extends stream.Writable
  constructor: ->
    super
      objectMode: true

  _write: (chunk, enc, next) ->
    console.log('Result chunk: ',chunk)
    console.log('Result enc: ',enc)
    console.log('Result parse: ',JSON.parse(chunk))
    next()
```

In the test

```
mock = express()
data = [
  {uuid: 'ac475cf4-ef10-4be2-8a65-665178f9682c', status: 'whatever'},
  {uuid: 'bc321fc3-fe70-5eb4-f968-9682c75cf455', status: 'great'}
]

mock.get('/processable', (req,res) ->
  res.json(data)
)
mock.listen(3000)
```

output:

```
Result chunk:  <Buffer 5b 7b 22 65 76 65  ....
Result enc:  buffer
Result parse:  [ { uuid: 'ac47 ....}, {...} ]
```

My expectation is that the ResultStream will get called per JSON object in the array, but I receive the entire array. Am I missing something or misunderstanding something?

Comment: `res.json(data)` will just flush the buffer and end the response in one go.

Comment: So Response.json() is not streaming, so my question is how I get an array being streamed in chunks in express.

Comment: thanks @marekful. I'm on a path now. I assume I can write() and end() in the Response or pipe a Readstream into the Response in my test. I have a stream on the actual endpoint